# HTML 5 semantic tags

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have read about some of the semantic elements on W3C, WHATWG, and MDN, but I still a little unclear on somethings. I also went to [this article, on Sidebar and Aside are different!](https://aastudio.fr/Sidebar-and-Aside-are-different.html).

I have a few basic questions, or confirm that I am understanding what I have read:

- Is the `aside` element not a sidebar?
- In HTML5, can we use semantic and `div` tags?
- When there are no semantic tags to use, is a `div` tag acceptable in HTML5 (this may be the same question as above)?
- Can the semantic `main` element have other semantic tags embedded within, such as `table`, `section`, `article` and `aside`, but not limited to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that semantic tags are just a way to keep the code more human readable and to standardize pages.

This is because before most users would define just `divs` and then a `class` describing its role like `nav`, `footer`, `header`, etc.

For your first question; no, an `aside` element does not represent a "sidebar" per se. It just represents content that is related to the main content, but it's not part of the main topic of the page. You could use it to wrap the contents of a sidebar (which is in itself a UI component), but you can use it for other things as well.

From [the HTML5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-aside-element):

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.
>
> The element can be used for typographical effects like pull quotes or
>   sidebars, for advertising, for groups of nav elements, and for other
>   content that is considered separate from the main content of the page.

For your second question.

Yes, in HTML5 you can use `divs` or semantic tags whenever you like, but it is encouraged that you use semantics whenever possible; if there's no other tag you can use to define part of the document, then use a `div` without problems. You can use them interchangeably, at the end, most of them like `main`, `section`, `footer`, etc. are just `divs` with a different name to make it easier to read.

Comment: Just to recap the first part your answer, The aside can be used as a sidebar, but it has other uses as well. which is stated in the HTML5 Spec link that you provided.  Thank for your answer. Some of the sites are not very specific on what how these elements can be used. It leavs me a little confused at times.

Comment: At the end remember you can put any content you want inside any of these HTML tags, the sidebar itself is a UI element that you would have to build using CSS as well, the html tag doesn't give any special format to the content you put inside; the most optimal use for the `aside` tag I would say is something like the "Related" section you see on the right in StackOverflow with other questions

Comment: So if I was doing a two-column layout sidebar and main content. If the sidebar is more for navigation of a website it would best to use <div class=mySidebar> vs <aside>, but if it is like StackOverflow with questions on the right side the <aside> would be more suitable.

Comment: Exactly, and actually if you will use one of the columns for the main navigation of the site, I would wrap the navigation links inside a `nav` tag, maybe something like  `<div class="mySidebar"><nav>List of links here</nav></div>`

Answer (score 2):

This has always caused great confusion. This is [the original specification's author - Ian Hickson - on the subject in 2009](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2009Sep/0240.html) (his responses are in bold, to comments made by Tab Atkins Jr):

> > 2. `<aside>` is similarly badly named. The name itself and the
> >        description of it as "sidebar" content apparently leads almost
> >        everyone astray into thinking it's for the ubiquitous website sidebar.
>
> **It is.**
>
> > An informal survey showed that at least 3 people in that chat (me
> >     included) immediately tried to misuse `<aside>` in *precisely* this way
> >     when we first heard of it, and when I discussed the issue with another
> >     friend mid-chat his response was roughly "what's confusing about them?
> >     footer is for site footer and aside is for side panels".
>
> **That is a correct interpretation.**

Comment: you will probably have a more accurate explanation for this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310655/one-of-my-divs-is-haunted-by-a-phantom-top-padding-seemingly-ignoring-my-css-fi#