# One of my divs is haunted by a phantom top padding, seemingly ignoring my css file

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a very simple navbar for the last two days, just a  with a few buttons inside, one of which is supposed to show a dropdown menu. I've set all my paddings with % and for the most part they work, except for the div containing the button that shows the dropdown menu.

```css
/* all fonts are using vw units as it makes it easier to spot the phantom top-padding */

header {
 background-color: #101010;
}
header h1 {
 color: #ffffff;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Barlow Condensed";
 font-size: 7vw;
 padding: 1%;
}
body {
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #f0f0f0
}
ul, ol { 
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
content {
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
}
nav {
 background-color: #999999;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: "Barlow condensed";
 outline: none;
 border: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover, .dropbtn {
 background-color: red;
}

/* This contains the dropdown */
.dropdown {
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 1.5%;
}

/* This is the button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
 font-size: 1.2vw;
 border-style: none;
 border-width: 0px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1.5%;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0%;
}

/* Dropdown contents */
.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 min-width: 10%;
 overflow: auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 1;
 margin-top: 1.5%;
 margin-left: -1.5%;
}

/* links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
 color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 float: none;
 font-size: 1.1vw;
 padding: 2%;
}

/* background color for links inside the dropdown (hover) */
.dropdown-content a:hover { 
background-color: #ddd;
}

/* shows the dropdown on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}
/* Other buttons in the nav bar, working as intended. */
.botons {
 float: left;
 font-size: 1.2vw;
 border-style: none;
 border-width: 0px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1.5%;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.botons a {
 float: left;
 font-size: 1.2vw;
 border-style: none;
 border-width: 0px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.botons:hover {
 float: left;
 font-size: 1.2vw;
 border-style: none;
 border-width: 0px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1.5%;
    background-color: red;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estil-index.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow Condensed' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo.png"
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="widht=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header><h1>Big header text</h1></header>
  <content>
   <nav>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Home</a></button>
     <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </div>
     </button>
    </div>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Regular button</a></button>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Button</a></button>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Button</a></button>
   </nav>
 </body>
```

As you can see, the .dropdown div (or maybe the button inside) is behaving erratically and instead of having a % padding like I specified **everywhere**, it sems to have a px padding, only on top, that grows in size as the screen becomes smaller or if zoomed in.

I've sent the code to several peers and friends who are as stumped as I am, especially by the fact that the phantom padding only appears on the top side.

Comment: add `line-height: 0;` to that button

Comment: Giving a `line-height:0` inside the `dropdown` class in css fixes it for me. Don't ask me why though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit tricky to explain but basically it's due to the fact the button is not made float as the `a` elements and there is the default `line-height` that define the height of the line box which will be bigger when the font-size get smaller. So the phatom padding is the height of the line box defined by the `line-height`.

An easy fix it to make the button floating like the links thus it will be a block level element and no more an inline level element.

```css
/* all fonts are using vw units as it makes it easier to spot the phantom top-padding */

header {
  background-color: #101010;
}

header h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Barlow Condensed";
  font-size: 7vw;
  padding: 1%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

content {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  background-color: #999999;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Barlow condensed";
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover,
.dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}


/* This contains the dropdown */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1.5%;
}


/* This is the button */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0%;
  float: left;
}


/* Dropdown contents */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 10%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-left: -1.5%;
}


/* links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  padding: 2%;
}


/* background color for links inside the dropdown (hover) */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* shows the dropdown on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Other buttons in the nav bar, working as intended. */

.botons {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.botons a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.botons:hover {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow Condensed' rel='stylesheet'>

<header>
  <h1>Big header text</h1>
</header>
<content>
  <nav>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Home</a></button>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </div>
     </button>
    </div>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Regular button</a></button>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Button</a></button>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Button</a></button>
```

Or reduce the `line-height` and adjust `vertical-align` to top:

```css
/* all fonts are using vw units as it makes it easier to spot the phantom top-padding */

header {
  background-color: #101010;
}

header h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Barlow Condensed";
  font-size: 7vw;
  padding: 1%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

content {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  background-color: #999999;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Barlow condensed";
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
}

.dropdown:hover,
.dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}


/* This contains the dropdown */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1.5%;
  line-height: 0;
}


/* This is the button */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0%;
  vertical-align:top;
}


/* Dropdown contents */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 10%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-left: -1.5%;
}


/* links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  padding: 2%;
}


/* background color for links inside the dropdown (hover) */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* shows the dropdown on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Other buttons in the nav bar, working as intended. */

.botons {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.botons a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.botons:hover {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5%;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow Condensed' rel='stylesheet'>

<header>
  <h1>Big header text</h1>
</header>
<content>
  <nav>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Home</a></button>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </div>
     </button>
    </div>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Regular button</a></button>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Button</a></button>
    <button class="botons"><a href="#">Button</a></button>
  </nav>
```

Comment: That more or less nails it, I think. Another alternative would be to move the `font-size:1.2vw` from the button to its div container, and set the line-height of the button to `inherit`, so that the line-height of the div's strut stays the same as that of the buttons.