# Fieldset and Legend tags in HTML?

Tags: html

So I was working with forms in HTML and here's the code that I used:

```
<form>
   <label>Date Of Birth</label>
        <select name="Month">
            <option value="Jan">January</option>
            <option value="Feb">February</option>
            <option value="Mar">March</option>
            <option value="Apr">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
        </select>
        <select name="Day">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
        <select name="Year">
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
        </select>
   </label>
</form>
```

Now, this is incorrect semantically.(At least that's what I understand). And to group the select tags, we use Fieldset and legend tags. Can anyone explain, what is the use of these two tags or how it groups them? Is there any other use of the two tags and/or are the tags dependent of each other?

Comment: [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) and [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) on MDN

Comment: self explanatory https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Comment: Thanks, but that was kind of my doubt. is that all these tags do? In the sense, group multiple select tags to a single group? Can't we use div to do that? P.S:I understand that Legend is used to caption the group.

Comment: @DorjayYolmo keep in mind that most **semantic** tags are basically `divs` with a different name, the idea is to make the HTML code more human readable and to standardize pages, instead of creating classes to "name" divs, it's better *semantically* to use the appropriate tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, the use of `fieldset` and `legend` tags are self-explanatory and you can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).

Regarding your question, **Yes**, you could achieve the same behavior and looks using `div`, `label`, etc; but this is both *semantically* incorrect as well as more work for you to replicate the same appearance. And the `legend` tag is dependent on a `fieldset` tag, since it need to have a reference to place itself on.

The ideal scenario would be that if there is an HTML5 tag for it, use it instead of a simple `div`, it helps to make the document more human readable and to keep it in line with most modern pages;

For reference I explained a bit more about semantic tags on this question as well
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229971/8437694

And this article helps explaining the benefits of semantic tags as well:
https://www.lifewire.com/why-use-semantic-html-3468271