# Is it acceptable to use section tag anywhere in the page?

Tags: html

Is it an acceptable practice to use section tag as a child anywhere in the page 
or it should be always a main tag???

For example:

```
 <section class="software-development">
   <h2>
     <span>Software</span>
     <span>Development</span>                   
   </h2>
   <div class="development-areas">
     <section class="web-apps">     
          <h2>Web Applications</h2>
          <p>dolor ipsum........</p>
     </section>
     <section class="mobile-apps"></section>
     <section class="desktop-apps"></section>
   </div>     
 </section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use almost any HTML tag for anything you want, but the idea of *semantic tags* is to give meaning to the content of your page.

In this particular case, you can use the `section` tag (or even the `article`) to define any self-contained part of your page, there's nothing wrong with that, in fact it IS a section after all with its own title. Don't think of the use of the tags as a hierarchy all the time; think of what the element your creating actually *is* in the page and use the appropiate tag;

This is a great article that can help you clear everything regarding semantic tags:
https://www.lifewire.com/why-use-semantic-html-3468271

Just a quote from the same article:

> Semantic HTML or semantic markup is HTML that introduces meaning to the web page rather than just presentation. For example, a `<p>` tag indicates that the enclosed text is a paragraph. This is both semantic and presentational, because people know what paragraphs are and browsers know how to display them.

More information for the `section` tag based on [Mozilla's Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section):

- > Each  should be identified, typically by
  >   including a heading (`<h1>-<h6>` element) as a child of the 
  >   element.
- > If it makes sense to separately syndicate the content of a `<section>` 
  >   element, use an `<article>` element instead.
- > Do not use the `<section>` element as a generic container; this is what
  >   `<div>` is for, especially when the sectioning is only for styling
  >   purposes. A rule of thumb is that a section should logically appear in
  >   the outline of a document.

You can read more in this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229971/8437694

Answer (score 1):

No, not *anywhere*. The [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element) say the following (emphasis mine):

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content, typically with a heading.
>
> *Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a
>   tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis.* A Web site's
>   home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news
>   items, and contact information.
>
> Authors are encouraged to use the article element instead of the
>   section element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of
>   the element.
>
> The section element is not a generic container element. *When an
>   element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A
>   general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the
>   element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's
>   outline.*

So `<section>` could easily be put almost anywhere without fighting against its semantics.

Technically, you can use `<section>` anywhere "where flow content is expected".