# Can i put aside tag outside of section tag?

Tags: html

I organise my code like this :

```html
<body>
  <section> section1 </section>
  <aside> aside (no relation with section 1 or 2)</aside>
  <section> section 2 </section>
</body>
```

But my teacher said that if i don't put the aside into section, i should put div instead aside.

Is there someone who can explain me why ?

Thank you.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229971/8437694)... This question is probably opinion-based and is likely to get closed... However, I don't think your teacher is exactly correct; in HTML5, *semantics* is important; you should use tags that accurately represent what the element you are building actually is, so you give *meaning* to the content instead of just presentation...

Answer (score 2):

welcome to the community.

Yes, you can. Let's start to find the reason why from the documentation regarding the **[semantic HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#Semantics_in_HTML)** that you pointed out `<section>` and `<aside>` and their formal definition.

#### [Section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element)

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.
>
> Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, and contact information.

#### [Aside](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-aside-element)

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content. Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.
>
> The element can be used for typographical effects like pull quotes or sidebars, for advertising, for groups of nav elements, and for other content that is considered separate from the main content of the page.

If we check who are the permitted parents of [`section`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) and [`aside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside), we will find out that any element that accepts [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) is allowed.

> Elements belonging to the flow content category typically contain text or embedded content.

Few example are: `<a>`, `<div>`, `<p>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>` and, surprise surprise also `<section>` and `<aside>`.

This means that both `<section>` and `<aside>` accept each other as a parent element.

```html
<!-- valid html -->
<body>
 <div>
  <section>
    <h1>Aside element with section parent</h1>
    <aside>
      <p>The Rough-skinned Newt defends itself with a deadly neurotoxin.</p>
    </aside>
  </section>
 </div>
</body>
```

```html
<!-- valid html -->
<body>
  <div>
    <aside>
      <section>
        <h1>Section element with aside parent</h1>
        <p>The Rough-skinned Newt defends itself with a deadly neurotoxin.</p>
      </section>
    </aside>
  </div>
</body>
```

### But most of all this also means that they can have a different parent element.

#### Here we go, we have proven the initial statement.

Here a few examples:

```html
<!-- valid HTML -->

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      This is anchor
      <aside>This is aside inside anchor</aside>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

```html
<!-- valid HTML -->

<body>
  <div>
    <blockquote>
      This is a paragraph
      <aside>This is aside inside blockquote</aside>
      <section>This is a section inside blockquote</section>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
aside {
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: .5rem;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  float: right;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 0 5px -5px #29627e;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #29627e;
}

aside>p {
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- valid HTML -->
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Salamanders are a group of amphibians with a lizard-like appearance, including short legs and a tail in both larval and adult forms.</p>

    <aside>
      <p>The Rough-skinned Newt defends itself with a deadly neurotoxin.</p>
    </aside>

    <p>Several species of salamander inhabit the temperate rainforest of the Pacific Northwest, including the Ensatina, the Northwestern Salamander and the Rough-skinned Newt. Most salamanders are nocturnal and hunt for insects, worms and other small creatures.</p>
  </div>
  </body
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Your fourth example is not valid HTML. The `<aside>` element will auto-close the `<p>` element making the `</p>` tag spurious, and the aside and section elements are not inside the paragraph as claimed by their content text.

Comment: You are right. Thank you to pointed it out. I've update the fourth example.